# android JsonObjectRequest error

Tags: android, json, outlook, httprequest, microsoft-graph-api

I try that my application was linked with ms outlook.
I complete ms login, then have to get outlook calendar id. In ms develop page, 
they asked me to send a http request to "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar"

I am getting:

> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "graph.microsoft.com": No address associated with hostname

```
String url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar";
final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.getcalendar);


RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                        (Request.Method.GET, url, parameters, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                textView.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                                Log.i("in onresponse","gdgd");
                            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("onErrorResponse", "Error: " + error.toString());

            }
        }) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer ");
        return headers;
    }
};
jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        3000,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Comment: Make sure you have internet connection, this is one of possibility of problem.

Answer (score 0):

UnknowHostException is a very generic error for when either proxy is down, network connection is down or DNS issue. Check the session that the process is running and see could there be a session timeout issue.

However, its seems like https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar is not a Get Method... try to change Get to Post Method

`Request.Method.POST` instead of `Request.Method.GET`

Comment: um.. ms say, 

<HTTP request
GET /me/calendar > .. i'll try!

Comment: BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars /// try to change method, i'm getting error that